# NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:

Tags: python

```
ROOT_DIR = "/content/LCDS/MalignantCases"

number_of_images = {} 

for dir in os.listdir(ROOT_DIR):

 
  number_of_images[dir] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir)))
```

---

when I run the code I get this error

```
NotADirectoryError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-4edc0f0385bd> in <module>()
   
   number_of_images[dir] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir)))

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/content/LCDS/MalignantCases/Malignant case (347).jpg'
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Sidenote: take a look at [`pathlib`](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/), it makes a lot of things much easier compared to `os`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check if the object is a file or a directory before attemting to call the `os.listdir()` method on it. You can do this using the [`os.path.isdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) method:

```
ROOT_DIR = "/content/LCDS/MalignantCases"

number_of_images = {} 

for dir in os.listdir(ROOT_DIR):
  joined = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, dir)
  if os.path.isdir(joined):
    number_of_images[dir] = len(os.listdir(joined))
```

A few things to note:

1. It is considered bad practice to define variables using names that are taken by built-in function, and in your case, `dir` is already the name of the built-in function [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir).
2. It is [recommended by PEP-8 to used 4 spaces as indentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) for optimal readability.